# PHP Appending an array with an additional Mysql Query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, append

I was hoping someone could show how to properly append an array created with an sql query with data from a second query.

I have an array I created from a mysql resource which is correct.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $first_pass[] = $row; 
}
```

But before I finish with the $first_pass array I want to do a second query, so inside the while loop before the $first_pass array I added;

```
$p = $row['productid'];
$gle = mysql_query("SELECT value FROM `extra_field_values` WHERE productid = $p' AND fieldid ='11' "); 
$goog = mysql_fetch_row($gle);
$row['google_cat'] = $goog[0];
```

my question is, no matter how I add this query to the existing array, when I dump it, it does not look like just another index added to the array. I have tried the mysql_fetch_row with my own created index and I have tried using mysql_fetch_array but then it shows as another array in the array.
I think it will function fine the way it is but it does not look proper.
This is what the dump looks like:

> > array0 
> >     =>array
> >     0 => string '3614' (length=4)
> >     'variantid' => string '3614' (length=4)
> >     1 => string '1406' (length=4)
> >     'productid' => string '1406' (length=4)
> >     2 => string '180-GL-QT-CAY-M' (length=15)
> >     'productcode' => string '180-GL-QT-CAY-M' (length=15)
> >     google_cat => 'Clothing> Gloves'

where google_cat looks nothing like the rest of the array. So any input is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is, your initial `$row` is populated using `mysql_fetch_array()` which defaults to using the `MYSQL_BOTH` fetch method.

This creates an array using both numeric indices and column name keys.

When you append your `'google_cat'` key, you're only creating an associative index.

Unless you're actually going to use the numeric indices, I'd recommend sticking to `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysql_fetch_array()`

Actually, what I really recommend is ditching the mysql extension all together and moving to [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Re: PDO -- http://web135.srv3.sysproserver.de/blog/index.php?/archives/10-Effective-PHP-Cargo-Cult-Programming.html :D (Just sayin' that recommending the user to ditch their current approach without explaining why isn't really the most educational response...)

Comment: But +1 due to `mysql_fetch_assoc();`, that makes sense.

Comment: @aendrew I've given up explaining why, it's exhausting. I figured a decent read through the PDO section of the manual aught to explain the benefits clearly

Comment: If telling people to move from a functional programming style to an object-oriented one is something you do a lot, why not either find or write a blog entry somewhere about the topic so you can simultaneously educate and not be as cryptic? Just a suggestion, not trying to be critical. (Like, I'd link to it myself if I knew of a good one...)

Comment: @aendrew I'm just surprised how prevalent the mysql extension still is in 2011. Anyone would think new PHP developers don't actually read the  manual... oh wait :(. Also, just because PDO is OO, doesn't mean you have to suddenly convert your entire app to be object oriented. Here's something I wrote on the topic http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/forum-replies.cfm?t=1234522

Comment: Thanks for the advice, switching to the mysql_fetch_assoc()defiantly cleaned up the array but I still could not get the appended data to look like the original array unitl I used a for loop with a key, a value, and the reference operator on the value, then I was able to create an addition assoc key and add the value and that worked great

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an error in your MySQL syntax. Try:

```
$gle = mysql_query("SELECT value FROM `extra_field_values` WHERE productid = '". $p ."' AND fieldid = '11';");
```

You could also try replacing `$row['google_cat'] = $goog[0];` with:

```
$row['google_cat'] = $goog[0][0];
```

...So it gives you the interior array of the first array in the multidimensional row return array. (Array array arraaayyyyyy...)

Comment: Thanks, That was just a typo when transering the code here. My resource and my row are what i'd expect. They are fine. My problem is I can seem to append more data from another query and get the final array to look like the original dump, but its still functional.

Answer (score 0):

First use the same method to get your arrays from mysql (either mysql_fetch_array or mysql_fetch_row) not both.

then you can use

```
array_merge($row, $goog);
```

to concatenate the arrays together.  beware the warning that if two elements have the same associative key the last one in the list will be the value of that key.

http://php.net/array_merge

Answer (score 0):

Error in your syntax man!

```
$gle = mysql_query("SELECT value FROM `extra_field_values` WHERE productid = $p' AND fieldid ='11' ");
```

Is missing an apostrophe...

Should be:

```
$gle = mysql_query("SELECT value FROM `extra_field_values` WHERE productid = '$p' AND fieldid ='11' ");
```

Comment: Thanks, that was just a typo into stack overflow. Its not missing in the code base